# How to achieve this workflow on git / github?

Tags: git, version-control

I have 2 computers. PC1 has some code that I uploaded to github following this tutorial http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html

```
git init
git add
git commit
git remote add origin <url>
git push -u origin master
```

Now I have another PC that I will use to work on the same project and I am stuck trying to link them to the same repository. fetching or pulling however seems to do nothing. My folder (local repository) is still empty. This is what I have done so far

```
git init
git remote add origin <same url>
git pull
```

I was wondering if anyone can help me with a few simple lines for this. I am new to git and the things i google online seem highly complicated.

[image]

Comment: Also note that the normal way to clone a repository is `git clone`.

Comment: From your question you mean you have two PCs having the code to push for the same repository?  the code snippet in your question pushes your code to github but you need to pull from master in another computer to have the changes in your second PC.  You need to clone your code in your second PC first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do:

```
git pull origin master
```

As you did not setup `master` as your `upstream` branch.

Alternatively you can update the `GIT` repository using [`git-fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and [`--track`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_tracking_branches) `origin/master`, as:

```
 git init
 git remote add origin <same url>
 git fetch -all
 git checkout --track origin/master
```

Following which you can simply run `git pull` to update local repo from remote.